# Difference between group algebra over a field and algebra over the same field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When is there a difference between the group algebra over a field and an algebra over the same field, that is generated by a multiplicative subgroup that is isomorphic to the group?
I think that for finite groups, the two notions should be the same, and that the difference occurs for some infinite groups?

Comment: What do you mean by "an algebra over the same field, that is generated by the group"?

Comment: Lets have a group G and a field F. I am wondering when is F[G] (the group algebra) different to the F-algebra generated by G?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "the F-algebra generated by G"?

Comment: I mean subalgebra of an F-algebra B generated by elements of G, where G is a subgroup of the B* ("linear span of G").

Comment: Your definition of the F-algebra generated by G seems very much to depend on B, and so is not well-defined.

Comment: Please don't self-delete your post.  That's unfair to the answerer who has spent time and effort in answering your question.  We can (and will) undelete it.

Answer (score 5):

An $F$-algebra $A$ generated by a multiplicative subgroup $G$ does not have to be isomorphic to the group algebra $F[G]$, regardless of any finiteness conditions.  For a very simple example, taking $F=\mathbb{Q}$, then $A=\mathbb{Q}$ is generated by the group $G=\{1,-1\}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra but is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[G]$.

In order to conclude that $A$ is isomorphic to $F[G]$, you need to additionally know that $G$ is $F$-linearly independent as a subset of $A$.  That means exactly that the canonical homomorphism $F[G]\to A$ which is the identity on $G$ is an isomorphism, since $F[G]$ consists of formal linear combinations of elements of $G$.